# Get the minimum value for multivariable

Tags: optimization, average

I need a way to calculate the very minimum of each variable for a grade average.

Each grade variable have a weighing percentage (I don't know if it's the right term)

The weighing sum must be the total (100%)

The value it must be `>=1` and `<=7`

For example

$$
0.25x + 0.2y + 0.25z + 0.3u = 4
$$
or any number of variables
$$
0.15x + 0.2y + 0.25z + 0.15u + 0.25w = 4
$$

So I need the minimum value for each grade/variable to match 4

How can I do that?

Sorry if it's a dumb question

Thanks

Comment: If there is no constraints on the variables, then there is no minimum value. Are the variables between 0 and 100?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\text{There are a lot of ways to define the minimum for the grades as a whole.}$$
$$\text{One way to define the magnitude for a set of values is distance from the origin.}$$
$$$$
$$\text{Use Lagrange Multipliers to compute the extreme values.}$$

$\text{Let } f(x, y, z, u) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + u^2$
$\text{Let } g(x, y, z, u) = 0.25x + 0.2y + 0.25z + 0.3u - 4 = 0$

$$\text{We wish to find the points of extreme values of }f \text{ about the constraint g.}$$

$$\vec{\bigtriangledown{f}} = \bigg(2x, 2y, 2z, 2u \bigg) $$
$$\vec{\bigtriangledown{g}} = \bigg(0.25, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3 \bigg)$$

$$\text{There exists }\lambda \text{ such that:  } \vec{\bigtriangledown f} = \lambda \cdot \vec{\bigtriangledown g}$$

$$\begin{align}
2x &= 0.25\lambda\\
2y &= 0.2\lambda\\
2z &= 0.25\lambda\\
2u &= 0.3\lambda
\end{align}$$

$$\text{Thus, }\lambda = 8x = 10y = 8z = \frac{20}{3}u$$

$$\text{Now, we can solve for one of the variables, say } x \text{ about the constraint.}$$
$$0.25x + 0.2(0.8x) + 0.25x + 0.3(1.2x) - 4 = 0 \space \implies \space x = \frac{4}{1.02} \approx 3.92$$
$$\text{Using the equality with } \lambda \text{ to find } y \text{, } z \text{ and } u \text{ is left as an exercise for the reader.}$$

Comment: Great! :)

Thank you!

Comment: @mallendeo Is this homework, or your curiosity?

Comment: Ok. Could you explain why minimize the distances from the origin?

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun My curiosity, it's because I'm making an Android app that get marks from a school website, so I'll try to do this in java

Comment: @AlexSilva It's actually a tad bit arbitrary. Let's say I have a set $G$ of grades. Before I begin to "minimize" this set, I have to give it some sort of norm function to define its magnitude. I chose a distance function.

Comment: @mallendeo In that case, I hope you find it straightforward to generalize these equations to $n$ variables. :P

Comment: @MohammadAliBaydoun, I understand you. But with your solution some grades which are negatives can be discarded. For the example, if a grade of $-4$ is possible, you don't reach it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to compute the minimum for $x$. Just set all the other variables $y=z=u=w=7$ and then solve for $x$.

Comment: That wouldn't give you a correct solution.

Comment: You understand the question differently? Why is your objective to minimise distance from the origin?! The OP wanted to "calculate the very minimum of each variable for a grade average".

Comment: Because I'm pretty sure he wouldn't want to fix every other grade before computing the minimum for a specified one. I think he wants to minimize all of them at once in some way. If he doesn't, then your answer would be correct, and I'd be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need just solve the problem:

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{c}
 minimize \hspace{1cm} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} x_i \\
s.t. \hspace{2cm} \sum \limits_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_ix_i = \beta \\
\hspace{3cm} a_i \leq x_i \leq b_i, i=1,\ldots, n. \\
\end{array}
\end{equation} Thus, you will find each minimal $x_i$ satisfying the constraints. This is an LP problem, which is easy to solve.

*Remarks:*

$(1)  \hspace{3mm}\sum \limits_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i = 1$, and $\alpha_i \geq 0$;

$(2) \hspace{3mm}$ Each $a_i > -\infty$, otherwise the problem has no solution, because some $x_j$ could diverge to $-\infty$.